# Not answered ItemContainerStyle Causing Telerik radTreeview to disappear. (WPF)

Tags: wpf, telerik

the application is based on MVVM using Prism with MEF.
I have converted  windows tree view control to Telerik RadTreeview control. everything worked fine except that the ItemContainerStyle defined is somehow disabling the tree to be shown.  if I remove the ItemContainerStyle from the Radtreeview the tree becomes visible but with not styling.
 by using the windows treeview with same ItemcontainerStyle work fine. 
Following is the code.

```
    <uxc:UxtWindow.Resources> 
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SiteWizardTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}" > 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayAs}" /> 
            </StackPanel> 
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
    </uxc:UxtWindow.Resources> 

 <telerik:RadTreeView IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Wizard.WizardSections}" 
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SiteWizardTemplate}"                                          
                               PreviewMouseDown="TreeView_PreviewMouseDown" > 
                               <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}"> 
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" /> 
                                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" /> 
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,10" /> 
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" /> 
                    </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>   

</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to extend the existing style with the `BasedOn` Property and not just override it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}}">
```

Oh and remove your `ItemTemplate`: You can't set both `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: Wow, just wasted a couple of hours troubleshooting this problem... All Telerik how tos do not use BasedOn but it is absolutely necessary to use it with their new explicit theming...  Thanks a lot.